# Which of my double and single quotes do I need to escape in my Bash script?

Tags: bash, quotes

I have this line in a for loop in a bash script:

```
gvpr -c \'N{pos=\"\"}\' ${FILE} | fdp -o data/${PAD}.${FILE} -Tdot -Nlabel='""' -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
```

I need the script to run (after expanding the variables) the following code:

```
gvpr -c 'N{pos=""}' 072.grafo1643.10.planar_drawn.dot | fdp -o data/1.test -Tdot -Nlabel="" -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
```

I don't know how to format the script to get these commands to run.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is the entirety of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "data" ]; then
    mkdir data
fi

for FILE in `ls`
do
    if [ $FILE != process.sh ] && [ -f $FILE ]; then
        fdp $FILE -o data/p.$FILE -Nlabel=\"\" -Nshape=point
        for i in {1..100}
        do
            printf -v PAD "%03d" $i
            gvpr -c \'N{pos='""'}\' ${FILE} | fdp -o data/${PAD}.${FILE} -Tdot -Nlabel='""' -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: show the whole script you have. and define "format".

Comment: Does it give you any specific error messages?

Comment: @bash-o-logist: with you I'd like to be able to bookmark a user, too. Given your useful answers so far. :)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @bash-o-logist: I'm referring to the answers as can be seen from your profile. I noticed your (fitting) nick already one or two days ago in a shell-related question. And I'm serious. No sarcasm meant. There are some gems to be found among your answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try not escaping some of your single quotes. I don't have `gvpr` or `fdp` so could not test. But you can give this a try and let me know the outcome

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir data 2>/dev/null
for FILE in *
do
    if [ "$FILE" != process.sh ] && [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        fdp "$FILE" -o data/"p.${FILE}" -Nlabel="" -Nshape=point
        for i in {1..100} # if you have Bash 4, you can do {001.100} 
        do
            printf -v PAD "%03d" $i
            gvpr -c 'N{pos=""}' "${FILE}" | fdp -o data/"${PAD}.${FILE}" -Tdot -Nlabel="" -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
        done
    fi

done
```

Comment: This worked!  I'm not too familiar with gvpr myself, so I didn't quite know what would be necessary.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Escaping the outer single quotes would definitely be wrong (as in `\'N{pos=\"\"}\'`). Single quotes don't evaluate variables (with `$`) inside of them. Thus only the single quote inside single quotes would have to be escaped.

```
gvpr -c 'N{pos=""}' "$FILE" | fdp -o "data/${PAD}.${FILE}" -Tdot -Nlabel="" -Nshape=point -Gstart="$RANDOM"
```

... should work from the syntactic point of view. Of course I don't know the commands `gvpr` and `fdp` to judge what they would expect.

Anyway, `'data/${PAD}.${FILE}'` would not yield what you want, because you want the variables inside to expand. Thus the use of `"data/${PAD}.${FILE}"` in my example.

Oh, and your expanded example contradicts what you gave above `"$FILE"` and `"data/${PAD}.${FILE}"` don't quite match in the expanded form ;)

And assuming that your `gvpr` command wants the string quoted *again*, you'd have to go for:

```
gvpr -c '\'N{pos=""}\'' "$FILE" | fdp -o "data/${PAD}.${FILE}" -Tdot -Nlabel="" -Nshape=point -Gstart="$RANDOM"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the outer single quotes in 'N{pos=\"\"}', I'd use:

```
gvpr -c "'N{pos=\"\"}'" ${FILE} | fdp -o data/${PAD}.${FILE} -Tdot -Nlabel='""' -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
```

Other option:

```
gvpr -c \''N{pos=""}'\' ${FILE} | fdp -o data/${PAD}.${FILE} -Tdot -Nlabel='""' -Nshape=point -Gstart=$RANDOM
```

(You don't need to escape double quotes in single-quoted strings.)

Comment: I think your second option is wrong. Not the outer single quotes (after `-c`) should be escaped? Or am I wrong?

Comment: The two options are equivalent in that regard: both echo "'N{pos=\"\"}'" and echo \''N{pos=""}'\' return 'N{pos=""}' with the outer single quotes. From the second code suggested by Precision, I am inferring that this gvpr command excepts to see the single quotes, and so you need to ensure that the shell don't remove then. I agree that this is unlikely, but this is what was requested...

Comment: I see. It's possible, yes. It's one of the options I also considered in my answer.